# Background image view behind a uitableview

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, xcode7

Is it possible to add an `imageView` behind a `UITableView`? How would I add this image:

[image: backGroundTexture]

So that users could see it behind a tableview (background set to clear)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "your_image_name")!)
```

As the function names imply, a `UIColor` is created from the image you supply.

Refer to the Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithPatternImage:) for more information.

Comment: This works, however the image looks to be upside down? How do I change the layout of this image if it isn't a variable?

Answer (score 1):

If you go into the Storyboard, you can insert the Image View, insert the image in, then in the Document Outline, you can move the image above the table and it'll go behind it. Then set the tableView alpha in the inspector as .5 or however opaque you want it.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with this is the text will also change opacity.

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I just did a tutorial that had this in it, but code was used instead of an image. In Swift 2.0 you create a file (let's call it BackgroundView) of type `UIView`, add this code in the pre-made `drawRect` function:

```
// Change these colors to the ones you want.
let lightPurple: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.377, green: 0.075, blue: 0.778, alpha: 1.000)
let darkPurple: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.060, green: 0.036, blue: 0.202, alpha: 1.000)

let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

//// Gradient Declarations
let purpleGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [lightPurple.CGColor, darkPurple.CGColor], [0, 1])

//// Background Drawing
let backgroundPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width, self.frame.height))
CGContextSaveGState(context)
backgroundPath.addClip()
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, purpleGradient,
    CGPointMake(160, 0),
    CGPointMake(160, 568),
    [.DrawsBeforeStartLocation, .DrawsAfterEndLocation])
```

Then create a `configureView` function in the `TableViewController` and put this line of code in it:

```
tableView.backgroundView = BackgroundView()
```

Then call the function in the `viewDidLoad`.